# Who were the people leaving Eureka in the first episode?

Tags: eureka, sy-fy

In the pilot episode of Eureka, it shows Marshal Carter and Zoe driving towards LA but zoe sees herself and Carter going in the other direction as they are about to enter Eureka.

Who were these people? (I'm only a few episodes into the 3rd season, so if it is explained later, please put it behind a spoiler block)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The series finale has an explanation of sorts:

> They're Carter and Zoe, on the way to drop Zoe off at the airport for her Harvard graduation. The show ends with this scene, with no explanation for what causes them to see themselves in the past/future, as a way of showing that just because the show is over doesn't mean Carter is going to stop having wacky problems to solve.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it was explained in that episode as some sort of paradox. She saw herself and Carter, either in the future or an alternate timeline.

I forget the name, but there's a type of paradox where **a series of events is caused by a singular event which itself was caused by the series of events it causes**.

So, essentially, the event that caused Zoe and Carter to go to Eureka was caused by Zoe and Carter in the future.

Comment: I think it's caleld the Bootstrap Paradox.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris The Bootstrap Paradox is specifically about information/objects that exist, but never came into existence.  It's a possible side-effect of a Stable Time Loop (or Back to the Future-style time manipulation (with the music style at the dance in the first movie)), where an event will, directly or indirectly, cause itself.

Comment: Hey now, what was wrong with my Jack Sparrow joke? Sheesh.